# Setting src of an image to a Chrome's extension stored file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is an example that shows what's my problem.

I'm writing a chrome extension that should replace google's logo in google main page (google.com). So I create a content-script that uses this javascript+jQuery code to do it (Please forgo google doodles!):

```
$("#hplogo").attr("src","the_address");
```

This content-script matches with `https://*.google.com/` which contains google's main page.

Okay. If I put in the_address an image address which is uploaded on the internet, the extension works properly and gives me ideal result.

But since I don't want my extension to make loading time long for slow connections, I'm going to set the image's src to a file from hard disk.

So I put the image file to extension's folder then I tried the file name (eg : image1.gif) as the_address, but this time, the chrome doesn't load the image.

What have I to do? Thanks, gúys.

Comment: For obvious reasons the image won't load, I assume it is still using the page's domain. You may need to use [`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL), which allows you to link resources from an extension directory

Comment: Yes, you're right. I could do it. Thank you. Why you didn't post it as an answer?

Comment: Maybe you were using `chrome.extension.getURL` already, there was no way to know without you providing more code. Well, there it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For obvious reasons the image won't load, I assume it is still using the webpage's domain. You may need to use [`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL), which allows you to link resources from an extension directory.

Comment: Don't forget to allow the source to be used in a non-extension context by adding it to the [`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) entry in the manifest file.